# Constructing InetSocketAddress from hostname and port adds slash at the beginning

Tags: java, sockets

I want to connect to a socket, reading hostname and port number from properties file. I've tried to create new instance of `InetSocketAddress` to pass it to `socket.connect` method, but it tends to add slash at the beginning, so it looks like `"/127.0.0.1"` for example. I am not using any `toString()`. No matter if I pass `"localhost"` or `"127.0.0.1"` or new `InetAddress(host, port)` the field `addr` inside `InetSocketAddress` is set to `"/127.0.0.1"`. Which causes `UnknownHostException`. 
Is there an elegant way to resolve host address for socket connection without trimming first character or using other libraries than javax.net?

Thank you in advance

Examples I've used:

`socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getHostAddress(), 1234), timeout);`

`socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1234), timeout);`

`socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1234), timeout);`

All of them produce socket addr = "\127.0.0.1"

Comment: Only to the result of `toString()`, which isn't used internally. No problem here to solve.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for comment. Funny thing is if there is `catch(UnknownHostException uhe)` statement when trying to connect socket, then it is catched because of this slash at the beginning (I think so), but if I comment it, then everything works. Probably that's my bad, because InetSocketAddress class is taking care of it internally. Am I right?

Comment: Can you break after it with a watch on the actual socket...? It would prove or disprove the ToString being a factor. Actually looks like you've done that already.